# How to limit ssh access for localhost only?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh, sshd

I need to forbid ssh access (except localhost) for specified user.

So. `ssh localhost` should work. `ssh hostname` from outside should not work for that user.

All other users should work as usual.

Comment: By the way, is this _user_ `root`?

Comment: @PedroRomano, no, it is not.

Answer (score 6):

See the `AllowUsers` and `DenyUsers` directives of the [`sshd_config` man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5) (and possibly also `AllowGroups` and `DenyGroups`).

Basically these directives take a list of user patterns in the `user@host` format separated by spaces. Directives have the following precedence: `DenyUsers`, `AllowUsers`, `DenyGroups`, and finally `AllowGroups`.

For the simple case of just allowing a specific user from `localhost`, only the following line should be added:

```
AllowUsers user@localhost
```

This will implicitly deny any user from anywhere that isn't `user@localhost`.

Comment: Thanks @PedroRomano So. As I have understood the manual I should add next lines to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:  DenyUsers user@* and AllowUsers user@localhost. Right?

Comment: no. my try is wrong...

Comment: No. Just add `AllowUsers user@localhost`. `DenyUser user@*` takes precedence over `AllowUsers` and will deny user from everywhere. By setting `AllowUsers user@localhost` you are only allowing that user from that host explicitly and denying everyone else from everywhere else implicitly.

Comment: yes, but this line affects also other users. All other users are denied. I do not want to touch other users....

Comment: What you need is unfortunately not trivial to achieve because of `Deny` always taking precedence over `Allow`. Can you create a group with all other users and add an `AllowGroup group@*` directive for that group?

Comment: unfortunately it does not work also.

Answer (score 4):

How about if you force public key authentication for the specific user, and then restrict his public key with a `from=` option in the authorized keys file.

To force a specific user to use public key authentication:

```
Match User Bad_User
    PasswordAuthentication no
    AuthorizedKeysFile /somewhere/the/user/cannot/touch
```

And then in the authorized keys file configure his key like this:

```
from=localhost ssh-rsa AAAA...
```

You can read more about `Match` directives in `man sshd_config`, and about authorized keys options in `man sshd`.

Comment: The downside is that as long as the user can login, they can also change their authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use PAM (UsePAM in sshd_config) and add

```
account  required     pam_access.so
```

to the PAM configuration for ssh.

Then you can define access policies in `/etc/security/access.conf`

```
+ : john : 127.0.0.1 ::1
- : john : ALL
+ : ALL : ALL
```

(untested)

Answer (score -1):

If you're happy to restrict TCP forwarding for that user, you can also configure this in your `sshd_config` file, which is normally at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, with a `Match` rule like the below:

```
Match User <username>
  AllowTcpForwarding no
Match User <username> Address *,!127.0.0.1,!::1
  ForceCommand /bin/false
```

This will enforce that anytime the user with the specified username logs in over SSH, if it's not from localhost (i.e. IP address 127.0.01 or ::1), the system will run `/bin/false` to return an error code, rather than running anything useful like a shell.

As [rudimeier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28765/rudimeier) [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53306/how-to-limit-ssh-access-for-localhost-only/443902#comment804089_443902), it's necessary to forbid port forwarding to avoid the user opening an initial SSH connection with port forwarding to localhost and no running command (e.g. using `-N` and `-L` arguments to OpenSSH), then opening a subsequent SSH connection through that tunnel, which would appear to be coming from localhost and therefore be allowed.

Comment: This does not work because `ssh -N` and port forwarding still works. The remote user could use `ssh server  -N -L 10022:localhost:22` and then get a shell by `ssh -p 10022 localhost`.

Comment: @rudimeier good spot, thank you! I've updated the answer to also include forbidding port forwarding, which I believe avoids that problem.